# Rust HashMap insert method producing borrow-checker error with generated string

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, borrow

I am trying Rust and having hard time to understand why the compiler fail my code on a lifetime issue. Here is the issue.

Here is how the code is organize using cargo workspaces.

```
.
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── README.md
├── collections
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   └── src
└── utils
    ├── Cargo.toml
    └── src
```

I defined a function in called `generate_string` in `utils` lib which I am calling from collections.

```
/// defined in utils/src/lib.rs
pub fn generate_string (size: usize) -> String {
    Alphanumeric.sample_string(&mut rand::thread_rng(), size)
}
```

Now trying to call it from collections/src/stone.rs

```
mod tets { 
   fn test_normalize_large_input() {
        let map_lenght = 50000;
        let err_message = "normalize handles large inputs.";
        let mut profile: HashMap<&str, f64> = HashMap::new();
        for _ in 0..map_lenght {
            let key: String = utils::generate_string(8);
            profile.insert(&key, 1.0); // this won't work
        }
        let got = normalize(&profile).unwrap();
        assert_eq!(got.len(), 1, "{}", err_message);
        assert!(got.contains_key("singleton"), "{}", err_message);
    }
}
```

I have a compilation issue.

```
    |
462 |             let key: String = utils::generate_string(8);
    |                 --- binding `key` declared here
463 |             profile.insert(&key, 1.0);
    |                            ^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
464 |         }
    |         - `key` dropped here while still borrowed
```

This is what I don't understand. I don't see which over variable or function is borrowing the variable `key`. Because the `insert` method of `HashMap` does not borrow the key args when I checked the documentation.

The the questions are, 1) What is actually borrowing `key` ? How can I insert the return of `utils::generate_string` in the Map without issue ?

I tried to clone the variable `key` this way `profile.insert(key.clone().as_str(), 1.0);`. I was expecting the cloning to duplicate the memory content so that the lifetime of key is no longer an issue. But it does not work either. I get another error this time.

```
    |
463 |             profile.insert(key.clone().as_str(), 1.0);
    |             ---------------^^^^^^^^^^^---------------- temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
    |             |              |
    |             |              creates a temporary value which is freed while still in use
    |             borrow later used here
    |
    = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
```

In reality, I do not want to clone the variable. I did tried this to see how it will behave.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: `profile.insert(&key, 1.0);` borrows from `key` as an `&str`. But `key` is a `String` which will be dropped (deallocated, destructed) at the end of the loop body. That's why you get the error. Change `profile` to a `HashMap<String, f64>` instead.

Comment: @PitaJ, I forgot to mention that the normalize function (normalize(&profile)) takes  HashMap<&str, f64> as argument. Is there any means to get it work without refactoring the normalize function ?

Comment: Where is the `normalize` function from?

Comment: There is one way but it's quite complicated: you need to create a vector which can own (hold) all the instances of `key` on behalf of the map. This can easily be done in two loops, first create a keys vector, then create a map from the borrows. However if you need to do it in a single loop [you need to mess around with borrow splits](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9948526d70345e40d4a8101a9f50a4e2) because containers can not be mutated (insertion or replacement of a value) while they have an outstanding borrow (the keys of the hashmap)

Answer (score 2):

> I don't see which over variable or function is borrowing the variable key. Because the insert method of HashMap does not borrow the key args when I checked the documentation.

`insert` does not but *you* do when you write

```
profile.insert(&key, 1.0);
```

That's a borrow. You're not inserting `key` in the map, you're inserting a reference to `key`.

And because `key` is a `String` which is owned by *the loop's scope* it is stopped at the end of that iteration, and thus the reference is dangling, which is illegal.

You need to make your map a `HashMap<String, f64>` so you can *move* `key` in the map, and the map owns the string from there on.

```
profile.insert(key.clone().as_str(), 1.0);
```

That's just a more complicated version of the same problem (an even worse problem in fact). `key.clone()` is a temporary which is dropped at the end of *the statement* (right after `insert` completes and returns), and you're inserting a reference to that temporary, which is an even shorter borrow.

You should really consider reading or re-reading the Rust book, carefully, because you're hitting your head against absolute fundamentals of the language here, and that's not going to be a fun experience. Rust is not an easy language, and unless you have master-class knowledge of C or C++ it is almost impossible to learn by just fucking around with in an editor, some of the concepts are novel, present in no non-academic languages, and as helpful as the compiler tries to be it will stop you hard and it can't provide complete guidance for the issues. Maybe one day, but not right now, and not any time soon.